# Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ and let $0<R<1$ prove that $\max_{|z|=R}{|f(z)|}=\frac{1}{(1-R)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ and let $0<R<1$ prove that $\max_{|z|=R}{|f(z)|}=\frac{1}{(1-R)^2}$

i am just starting with suppose $f(z)>\frac{1}{(1-R)^2}$ for some $|z|=R$ but i cant go for further

Comment: Is that a $\max$ or a $\sup$?

Comment: Hint: Reverse triangle inequality on numerator

Comment: max not sup ...@Fimpellizieri

Comment: Hint: Note that $|(1 - z)^2| = (1 - z)(1 - \bar{z}) = 1 - 2\mathrm{Re}(z) + R^2$ for $|z| = R$. Try minimizing this.

Comment: Even more: $\max_{|z|\le R}{|f(z)|}=\frac{1}{(1-R)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\max_{|z|=R}\frac{1}{|1-z|^2} = \left(\min_{|z|=R}|1-z|^2\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{|1-R|^2} $$
since the point on the circle $|z|=R$ closest to $z=1$ is pretty obviously $z=R$.